# Pure CSS Parallax with JS/jQuery Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've managed to create a Pure CSS Parallax, however, I'm having some difficulty with `scrollTop` while `overflow: hidden`is applied to `html`.

The CSS requires `overflow: hidden` either on the `html` tag or whatever relevant container and `overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto` on the `body` tag or whatever relevant container.

In any case where the `overflow` is applied, whether on `html` and `body` tags or otherwise, `scrollTop` does not work.

I have been able to detect scroll on the body, either to trigger an `alert` or to `addCLass`, but I would like to `removeClass` once the user scrolls back up to the top of the page.

Here's my code, so far, this is after trying various other normal solutions that work with `overflow` removed from the `html` element. This solution only adds the relevant class on scroll.

HTML

```
<header>
</header>
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="sheet-1">
    <h1 class="page-header">My Parallax</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="sheet-2"></div>
</div>
```

SASS

```
\:root
  font-size: 10px

*, *::before, *::after
  box-sizing: border-box
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
  text-decoration: none

html
  overflow-y: auto

body
  height: 100vh
  overflow-y: auto
  overflow-x: hidden
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
  perspective: 0.1rem

header
  height: 5rem
  width: 100%
  background: black
  opacity: 0
  position: fixed
  top: 0
  left: 0
  z-index: 999
  transition: opacity 1.5s ease
  &.black
    opacity: 1
    transition: opacity 1.5s ease

.parallax
  transform-style: preserve-3d

.background
  height: 100vh
  width: 100%
  background: url('https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/LWRWOL8KSV.jpg')
  background-size: cover
  transform: translateZ(-0.1rem) scale(2)
  position: relative

[class*='sheet-']
  min-height: 100vh
  display: flex
  align-items: center

.sheet-1
  position: absolute
  top: 0
  left: 0
  transform: translateZ(-0.05rem) scale(1.5)

.page-header
  color: white
  font-size: 4rem
  text-align: center
  text-transform: uppercase
  letter-spacing: 0.15rem
  margin: 0 auto

.sheet-2
  background: url('https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/P3IB71W6GW.jpg') no-repeat center center
  background-size: cover
```

JS

```
$("body").on("scroll",function(){
     $('header').addClass('black');
});
```

You can view the project on Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/jobaelish/pen/dZydJN#code-area).

Comment: Has you resolved this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no I haven't.

Comment: @Ivan86, I was able to resolve the matter with plain old Javascript. You can view the link again and see my solution. There is a solution for jQuery, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation was able to be resolved by monitoring the scroll event on the container.

In advance,sorry for the poor organization and structuring of the classes. Was roughing through some old code.

**Compiled HTML**

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="backdrop" id="backdrop"></div>
    <div class="logo" id="pos"></div>
    <nav class="navi">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#secondSection">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="=#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="=#">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="prlx" id="prlx">
  <div class="prlx-g">
    <div class="prlx-layer prlx-bg"></div>
    <div class="prlx-layer prlx-fg sheet">
      <h1 class="page-header">My Parallax</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cover sheet" id="secondSection"></div>
</div>
```

**Compiled CSS**

```
:root {
  font-size: 10px;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.header {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
.wrapper .backdrop {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.75s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.wrapper .backdrop.black {
  opacity: 1;
}
.wrapper .logo {
  height: 70%;
  width: 150px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.wrapper .navi ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
.wrapper .navi ul li {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.15rem;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.wrapper .navi ul li a {
  color: white;
}

.prlx {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -webkit-perspective: 0.1rem;
          perspective: 0.1rem;
}

.prlx-g {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.prlx-layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.prlx-bg {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/LWRWOL8KSV.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-0.1rem) scale(2);
          transform: translateZ(-0.1rem) scale(2);
}

.prlx-fg {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-0.05rem) scale(1.5);
          transform: translateZ(-0.05rem) scale(1.5);
}

.sheet {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.page-header {
  color: white;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.15rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cover {
  background: url("https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/P3IB71W6GW.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
// Get Scroll Position

var prlx = document.getElementById("prlx");

prlx.onscroll = function prlxAnimation() {
 var prlx = document.getElementById("prlx");
 var scrollPos = prlx.scrollTop;
 var header = document.getElementById("backdrop");
 // document.getElementById ("pos").innerHTML = y + "px"

 if(scrollPos > 10){
        header.classList.add("black");
    }
    else {
        header.classList.remove("black");
    }

}
```

The same pen is still in use on Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/jobaelish/pen/dZydJN#code-area).

Answer (score -1):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll= $(window).scrollTop();
```

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"/>
  
  
$(window).scroll(function(){
 var scroll= $(window).scrollTop();
$(".background").css("background-position","center "+(scroll*0.2)+"px");
});
```

```css
:root {
  font-size: 10px;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.header {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
.wrapper .backdrop {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.75s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.wrapper .backdrop.black {
  opacity: 1;
}
.wrapper .logo {
  height: 70%;
  width: 150px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.wrapper .navi ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
.wrapper .navi ul li {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.15rem;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.wrapper .navi ul li a {
  color: white;
}

.prlx {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -webkit-perspective: 0.1rem;
          perspective: 0.1rem;
}

.prlx-g {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.prlx-layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.prlx-bg {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/LWRWOL8KSV.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-0.1rem) scale(2);
          transform: translateZ(-0.1rem) scale(2);
}

.prlx-fg {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-0.05rem) scale(1.5);
          transform: translateZ(-0.05rem) scale(1.5);
}

.sheet {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.page-header {
  color: white;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.15rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cover {
  background: url("https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/P3IB71W6GW.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="backdrop" id="backdrop"></div>
    <div class="logo" id="pos"></div>
    <nav class="navi">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#secondSection">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="=#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="=#">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="prlx" id="prlx">
  <div class="prlx-g">
    <div class="prlx-layer prlx-bg"></div>
    <div class="prlx-layer prlx-fg sheet">
      <h1 class="page-header">My Parallax</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cover sheet" id="secondSection"></div>
</div>
```

hope this code works

Comment: Your first line is not valid JavaScript